# update dictionary in python from line data

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension

I have a script where I read a file line by line and save some information to lists and dictionary. Namely, I store the keys (say ley1 and key2) to pass to the dictionary and a list to be stored as item in the dictionary.

It happens that I have to update a dictionary only if some conditions are met, i.e.:

```
myDict = {}
if mylist:
    myDict[key1][key2] = mylist
```

Of course this will raise a KeyError if key2 does not exist already. Therefore, I introduced the following function:

```
def updateDict2keys(myDict,mykey1,mykey2,myitems):
    """
    updates a dictionary by appending values at given keys (generating key2 if not given)
    input: key1, key2 and items to append
    output: dictionary orgnanized as {mykey1:{mykey2:myitems}}
    """
    try:
        myDict[mykey1][mykey2] = myitems
    except KeyError:
        myDict[mykey1] = {mykey2:myitems}
    # output
    return myDict
```

My question is: is it "safe" to call such a function in the main code *inside a for loop* like this?

```
with open(os.path.join(path+myfile)) as ntwkf:
    # read file
    rdlistcsv = csv.reader(ntwkf)
    rowslist  = [line for line in rdlistcsv]
ntwkJuncDict = {}
for idx,f in enumerate(rowslist): # loop over file lines
    if f:
        lineelmnt = f[0].split()[0]
    else:
        continue
    # flags
    isBranchName = True if lineelmnt=='definitions' else False
    isJunction = True if lineelmnt=='connections' else False
    # update dictionary
    if isBranchName:
        reachname = f[0].split()[2].replace("'","")
    if isJunction:
        usreach = f[0].split()[2].replace("'","")
        uschain = float(f[1].replace("'","").replace(" ",""))
        if usreach: 
            uslist = [usreach, uschain]
            todivide.append(uslist)
            ntwkJuncDict = updateDict2keys(ntwkJuncDict, reachname, 'upstream', uslist)
```

I must say, my code works pretty well, I am just asking myself (and yourselves of course!) if I am doing everything the python way and if there are smarter solutions.

Comment: Are you aware of [``dict.setdefault``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I could use it to add non-existing keys, but how can I use it to update existing one by adding sub-keys? azro solutions do exactly what i need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing the primary key, use `dict.setdefault` with a default empty `dict` on it.

```
def updateDict2keys(myDict,mykey1,mykey2,myitems):
    myDict.setdefault(mykey1, {})[mykey2] = myitems
    return myDict
```

Note that your initial approach is also safe. Only lookup, not assignment, throws `KeyError`. In the statement `myDict[mykey1][mykey2] = myitems`, a `KeyError` can only be thrown of `mykey1` is not set. Thus, setting it to an empty `dict` on a `KeyError` does not overwrite anything.

Comment: Thanks! That's also doing what I need, and it looks like it's faster than azro's solution. Profiling results: azro 7.1e-06 s, MisterMiyagi 1.9e-06 s. Your solution should also be on the safe side concerning the erase of dictionary's previously stored data

Comment: after reading your comment to azro's answer, which confirms what I was thinking, and after doing the profiling I mark your answer as correct.